# How can I place the product on a social media post better?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, designers, layout, white-space

*(The Logo in corner and product label is hidden for privacy reasons)*

When I finalized the design, I got the feedback that the product (the grey thing in bottom left) **isn't fitting well**. (Image 1). So I did place it little above (Image 2). It looked better, still I got feedback that it is *floating in the air*.

So I believe, there's something wrong and I don't know how can I fix it. It's an air purifier. It has to be placed on left and should look better than these options. What can be done?

Also, you may suggest other possible way also, if you don't want to place it on left only. But the priority is left side, because the product name is mentioned on that side.

[image]

PS: Besides, generally asking, what else do you see wrong and can be improved to make it more aesthetic?

Comment: Does it have to include the obnoxious "like, share, comment, favourite, do everything or else" stuff?

Comment: First thing that strikes me is that you have a small icon that looks like the back of an iPhone next to the words "like, comment & share", and I assume it is asking me to interact using my phone. Maybe with the logo there that wouldn't be the case, but I suspect it still would be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have the feeling you are answering your question, maybe unconsciously.

Try to see the reading order:

[image: reading order]

Knowing the western reading order is from top to bottom, from left to right, the reader's eye will try to follow that path.

There's an object that first calls the eye attention: the girl picture. With the tendency to start from top to bottom, our eye will immediately goes to the beginning of the title, specially by the size, together with the reading sense and color.

After the stop at the logo, then the visual way goes down and finally left, where the orange bubble and the product are. All the elements at the bottom are absorbed by the picture, because they are interpreted as the ground. That's why in the sense of reading they are relegated to the end.

---

If we make the exercise with basic shapes it's more clear:

[image]

There is a large central object pointing to the title as a triangular arrow shape. Following the reading sense, the top objects, and from there to the bottom.

---

On the other side there's the disadvantage that the product is light grey, the color that less contrasts throughout the whole composition.

The color exercise shows how the contrast plays against the product. Imagine someone trying to remember the colors after seeing the add for a minute: the product doesn't exist.

[image: colors]

If this were my job I would change the color of the girl's pants to eliminate a dominant and irrelevant color. With this simple change (also softening the green of the back plant), the product gains more presence:

[image]

Finally, why I think you have answered your question, you have placed the images number on the place of greatest visual relevance, so that whoever reads your question sees it clearly. Halfway between the beginning of the reading order and the main element after the photo, the title. The best site in the whole composition to place the product.

[image]

Unlike the second example, where the product is levitating, *floating in the air*, here it will be hanged in the wall.

Where would you put a clock in this scene?

[image: Clock]

**Insert after the comment**

I follow with the clock example.

> Suppose the users haven't seen that product. They'll read the text "POCKET AIR PURIFIER" and might not know that the product is in picture. They might think that it's just part of the background image.

The only elements that visually compete with the clock in that position are the objects located behind the model. The reader unconsciously creates the perspective and defines a background where everything is located on the wall at the same level. We must find find a way that the rest of the elements get *behind the clock*, not literally but visually behind.

Here's an example blurring the background completely. It's something unreal, because the clock would be hanging between the back wall and the girl, but a very good visual resource to highlight the product even more. On the other side, blurring the background creates a *noise-cleaning* effect.

[image: background blur]

**Second edit:**

> Why is the product flying in the air?

[image]

The product must be somewhere in the whole composition, in graphic design you don't have to please everyone, but find the right answer to define why everything is in its place. I think this whole answer gives you enough reasons to justify the product position. If the product was the clock, you might think about the location of the last picture, following the double virtual guide generated by the sleeves and collar of the model T-shirt and her shoulders (1). But unfortunately your product doesn't have much visual presence, so you have to give a predominant place in the entire composition, that's why it's in the central place with the large blank space around.

(1) - There's an indirect perception associated with this position: the healthy product is in line with the heart.

---

What would you answer to this: **why did you put a girl instead of an elephant?**

Well, the same reasoning you would do for this answer you should do it for answering about the product position.

Comment: Your suggestions are excellent. I liked your idea about flow and dominant colors. Will surely do that. Now, the main problem was product. Suppose the users haven't seen that product. They'll read the text "POCKET AIR PURIFIER" and might not know that the product is in picture. They might think that it's just part of the background image. The point to keep the product nearby text was only this. (I like your placement of product just like a Watch). What do you say?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I got this feedback: Why is the product flying in the air?

Comment: Answer updated II (the last one :-))

Comment: Hahaha I have the same feeling. I wish I could say this to them :P But some people don't understand. So I already did the thing you did in 2nd edition. Little closer to bubble but ALSO ADDED a little shadow to the product at bottom. Is it a good idea or may look weird?

Comment: I personally think a shadow adds dirt, noise. I assure you your product doesn't need any of that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please tell me where can I learn the things you corrected for my design, for example, like the one about changing color of clothes, that faded plant?

Comment: Lol, years of experience I guess. Look for visual perception bibliography. One of the classics is *Art and Visual Perception* by Rudolph Arnheim.

Answer (score 13):

I, personally, won't *never* rely on the lower left corner of an advertisement to convey *anything*. It's a dead zone, easily forgotten or overlooked by the viewer.

I, perhaps mistakenly, get the feeling that there may be more imagery than what your samples show. If not, then it may be merely due to the usage in your samples.

Trying to **force** the lower left corner to be seen and read/remembered, for me, *often* throws something out of balance. Things just don't "feel" correct if there's actual text content in the lower left corner. I try and stick to *visuals only* for the lower left of anything, never type objects.

By placing the explanatory content above the Call to Action (CTA) items, you present a direct, memorable action... win this.. click here...

In addition, visually...

- the woman's arms lead the viewer in a clockwise circle when reading.
- They immediately pull the eye up to the headline
- reading right to left, you hit the explanatory content
- The icon/image being above the box of text pulls the eye into that text
- Placing the image/icon on the right side of the box tells the eye to move to the left
- Then the eye moves down to the CTA
- Then her left arm leads the eye up to the left again.

A clockwise circle is *always* a good thing.

[image]

Very rough draft.

I *may* search for a different "yoga/meditation-style" image, though. One with a post that also looks relaxing, however also has more of a pull upward and left.

For example...

[image]

Perhaps not *this* photo specifically (it was only a 15 second Google search for it).... but something with a similar angle. 3/4 views are always more interesting to me than front facing photos of people - they tend to pull the viewer *into* the image in a subtle way.

Comment: Any specific reason to change the BG color of bubble? As I've commented on @danielillo answer, would you please respond to it (maybe here)?

Comment: By using the same color for primary items it somewhat drags the eye along... healthy.... comment and win... share.. I might also change "KEEP", or even "KEEP MYSELF HEALTHY" all teal... I'd have to test visually to be certain.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Same Colors of what?

Comment: You lead the eye via color.. teal "health"... teal "Win"...teal "share"

Comment: As usual, I got a lot to learn from you. But the other answer solved my problem better. Thank you :)

Comment: Just asking, where can I learn/read/watch such things about design, like left bottom is dead zone?

Comment: Well, I learned it all in college, decades ago. Then have merely gained more solid footing through years of experience. I wouldn't know where to look for books or resources today.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a glass floor!
1, move the product to apparent position.
[image: step1]
2, a glass floor, use rectangel marquee, give it a feather to make it fluent.
[image: step2]
3, with that selection, create curve layer, make it subtle like glass, for the purpose of this post I make it apparent.
[image: step3] 
4, ctrl+G to make it in a group, add a layer mask, mask out person and product itselt, to make it perspective.
[image: step4]
5, go back to glass layer mask, ctrl+T do some perspective and scale thing.
[image: step5]
6, a shadow: select the product in background layer, make a curve top layer, make it dark, and ctrl+T to fit it proper position (from the person you can see lightsource is kind of from left).
[image: step6]
7, ctrl+G to make it in a group, add a mask, mask out product itself, maybe blur edge a little.
[image]
All done! It's all about subtlety - go back to adjust glass and shadow brightness.