# Something's missing in my homepage design

Tags: photo-editing

[image]

I can't tell what is missing in my home page. I am working with a designer who is also quite new at this. Could anyone point something out please

Comment: The head is cropped [unnaturally](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/125957/3270)

Comment: This question is opinion and requirements based.

Comment: @Scott well that's my question actually :D

Comment: @Vikas and Scott - absolutely the biggest problem here is that missing head and the general photo composition. While close crops are certainly in-vogue at the moment, this is just too much. It's not only the head but the chopped off hand too.

Comment: @BillyKerr I understand but we never know it was intentional or *mistake*.

Comment: @Vikas - if it is intentional then it is still a mistake. ;)  I've done quite a bit of portrait photography and in particular, hair fashion photography over the years, and this is a huge no-no IMHO

Comment: @BillyKerr yes, I feel it could be intentional. But I think he should crop it even more so it doesn't look live just head is severed.

Comment: @Vikas Close crops are quite common in fashion these days, but the total chopping off heads and hands is not.  Something [like this](https://imgur.com/6zxU7Cf) would be better.

Comment: @BillyKerr yeah better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit opinion based, but I'll give you my opinion anyway. I don't think there's anything actually wrong with the layout of the page. I'm not too fond of the bright red band, but that's more of personal taste thing.

I think the main problem is the crop of the photograph.  Totally chopping off heads and hands is a big no-no in photo composition in general. I've done quite a bit of portrait and hair fashion photography over the years, and bad cropping can just ruin the vibe and appeal of an image.  While close cropping is certainly in-vogue at the moment, particularly to concentrate the viewers attention on the garment or some other aspect of fashion, this is just a bit too much IMHO.

Perhaps consider a crop like this instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Vic - nothing to do with the design per se, but you may also want to rethink the slogan "get a compliment to your flawless beauty". It sounds like very awkward English.

Answer (score 0):

Things you could improve on:

- that man needs a face. also that photo is blurry and processed like its the 90's again. use sharp, natural looking photos
- everything is too dark
- modern fashion shops will start with men and women categories directly. homepage, about us and contact us should be moved to the footer and/or gray topbar. look at h&m or something
- logo too complicated and squeezed in there
- what is "flawless beauty" ?

Comment: Thanks for your insight.